# Core/translate Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Can you tell me how to do the same thing on Magento 2?

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->init('frontend', true);
```

Comment: what you actually want to do?

Comment: I see this line of code in a module magento 1 that i want to replicate on magento 2. I wanted to study it well on magento 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no need to do this programmatically. Magento 2 Admin provides an option to enable or disable inline translation. Below image will help you to do this.

[image]